# Close to diffraction grating

Tags: diffraction

Being interested in the diffraction of a coherent laser close to the diffraction grating, I find nowhere what the pattern looks like relatively to the distance between a diffraction grating and the screen (I'm ok with Fraunhofer diffraction).

I found here the name of the different regimes : http://optics.hanyang.ac.kr/~shsong/4-Fresnel%20and%20Fraunhofer%20diffraction.pdf but I still don't understand this "very near field" behavior (although the far-field diffraction appears every-where)...

Can someone help me understand what does this close to the grating diffraction look like (and if possible show me picture) ?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM32sxc3sxs

Comment: Have a look here: [http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.2108.pdf], especially Figure 1. The formalism is applied to X-rays, but is generally valid.

Comment: @Doru Constantin : Thanks a lot, it was what I was looking for !